# How can I convert in AWK a decimal value to hexadecimal value and store in in a variable?

Tags: awk

I am writing an AWK script and I am trying to store an hexadecimal result to a variable as an hexadecimal.

The proble is that after the calculation has taken place, I become a decimal number as return value and I need to convert it to hexadecimal.

The Code is the following:

```
number1 = 0x803FEFFF
number2 = 0x803FEAE0

# tempAddition is decimal 1311, but I need the hexadecimal format which should be 51F.
tempAddition = (strtonum(number2) + strtonum(number1))
```

I need to store the result in tempAddition variable as hexadecimal.

If you have any idea how the convertion can be written in AWK, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Use `sprintf`, e.g:

```
tempAddition = sprintf("0x%X", number1 + number2)
```

Since you've declared `number1` and `number2` as numbers, you don't need `strtonum` on them, but in order to use `tempAddition` as a number, you'll need it.

Comment: Actually the expression: 

```tempAddition = sprintf("0x%X", number1 + number2)```

returns 0x0.

In order to have the right value, we have to write the code as such: 

```tempAddition = sprintf("0x%X", (strtonum(number1) + (strtonum(number2)))```

@oguz ismail: Thank you for the information. It was really helpful.

Comment: @Origamer7 can't reproduce 0x0 here, which version of gawk are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the right value, we have to write the code as such:

`tempAddition = sprintf("0x%X", (strtonum(number1) + strtonum(number2)))`

@oguz ismail: Thank you for the information. It was really helpful.